# Symfony JEditable retrieve cached results using url_for()

Tags: php, javascript, datatables, jeditable

I am having the sort of same cache problem, and couldn't get it fixed with above solution. I am using Symfony 1.4, JQuery and JEditable.

Please check out this code:

```
$('#example tbody td').click( function () {

    /* Get the position of the current data from the node */
    var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );

    /* Get the data array for this row */
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData( aPos[0] );
    var d = new Date();
    var data_id = aData[0]*d.getMilliseconds();

    //oCache.lastJson.aData[aPos[0][aPos[1]] = sValue;
    //oTable.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1] );

    //alert("aData:"+data_id);
    $('td.cSelect').editable(
        '<?php echo url_for('mymodule/get_data?rid=') ?>'+data_id, 
        { 
              data      : '<?php print  json_encode($array); ?>',
              id        : data_id,          
              type      : 'select',
              submit    : 'OK'
        }
    );
    /* Update the data array and return the value */
    aData[ aPos[1] ] = 'clicked';
    this.innerHTML = 'Select';
} );
```

Please HELP me!!!

Comment: problem is at: 

<?php echo url_for('mymodule/get_data?rid=') ?>'+data_id

data_id is being sent from cache all the time, where it should send different values everytime click event is called

Comment: I've found the solution, it wasn't on JQuery or Jeditable, but on Symfony, was stupidly using hard-coded values.

Answer (score 0):

To change the URL where the data is posted to, you need to *destroy* the editable element first. So, if you do that right before you call `.editable()`, it should work as expected.

```
$('td.cSelect').editable('destroy');
$('td.cSelect').editable(
    '<?php echo url_for('mymodule/get_data?rid=') ?>'+data_id, 
    { 
          data      : '<?php print  json_encode($array); ?>',
          id        : data_id,          
          type      : 'select',
          submit    : 'OK'
    }
);
```

Comment: Using 'destroy' leads to stop working the JEditable. But thanks, I've found the solution, it was on Symfony!

Comment: That's why you re-initiate it right after you destroy it... Anyways, if you found your solution, you may want to post it here, so others who have the same problem as you can benefit from it.